# can maximum subarray problem be solved recursively in O(n) time?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

i know that divide and conquer approach for solving this problem whose time complexity is O(nlog(n)), but can we do better?

for example, can we apply same technique used for calculating nth Fibonacci term where we create a "tree recursion" along with extra memory for memoization to achieve a time complexity of O(n).

im asking this because this is considered a dynamic programming problem, and all dynamic programming problems i have encountered so far can be solved recursively and use the same technique, such as "house robber" and of course, calculating nth term of Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Do you mean "maximum **sum** subarray"?

Answer (score 0):

We can solve it recursively in O(n) time complexity, where n is length of given array. A sample approach in C++ would be as follow:

```
 void maxSubarrayRecursive(vector<int>& nums, int pos, int sum, int& max_sum) {
        if (pos == nums.size()) return;
        sum += nums[pos];
        max_sum = max(max_sum, sum);
        if (sum < 0) {
            sum = 0;
        }
        maxSubarrayRecursive(nums, pos + 1, sum, max_sum);
   }

   int main() {
        vector<int> nums = {1, 2, -1, 4, 3, 0, -10, 10};
        // sample nums array to find out max subarray sum
        int max_sum = INT_MIN;
        maxSubarrayRecursive(nums, 0, 0, max_sum);
        cout<< "Maximum subarray sum is: "<<max_sum<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but that's not the approach i was looking for